# uwsgi, how to keep log file size contained?

Tags: logging

my current uwsgi.log file size is 365M ..

I'd like to keep this file's size 50M max.
uwsgi documentation doesn't say how I can do it.

Should I use 3rd party solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On *nix I recommend [`logrotate`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html).  With your specifics, place a file inside `/etc/logrotate.d` with the following content:

```
/path/to/uwsgi.log {
    missingok # no error if the logfile is missing
    size 50M # rotate log file when size > 50 MB
}
```